# Get installed application details programatically for opening a pdf

Tags: android, android-intent, android-package-managers, android-implicit-intent

I am working in an android application and I want all the app details in my android device by which I will be able to open my pdf.

For example, by using implicit intent we will be able to see all the app name in a dialog by which we can select an app. Like that I want to create a dialog in which I can show all the app name which can be used to open my pdf.

Answer (score 0):

http://pilcrowpipe.blogspot.it/2012/01/creating-custom-android-intent-chooser.html suggests that using [`PackageManager.queryIntentActivities()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) could work.